# With or without class wrappered in C++

Tags: c++

I have a basic question since I havent used C++ in a while.

I have a header file like so:

It will remain the same, however the cpp file will change

```
#ifndef DOG_H_
#define DOG_H_

class Dog : Animal {
private:
    std::string breed;
public:
    Dog(std::string name, int age, std::string);

};



#endif /* DOG_H_ */
```

and then CPP version 1:

```
#include "Dog.h"



Dog::Dog(std::string name, int age, std::string breedIn){
        Animal(name, age);
        breed = breedIn;
    }
```

or CPP Version 2:

```
#include "Dog.h"

class Dog{


Dog::Dog(std::string name, int age, std::string breedIn){
        Animal(name, age);
        breed = breedIn; // the var name breed does not resolve
    }
};
```

The difference between version 1 and version 2 is that the 2nd one is wrapped in the `class` definition.

Why should I do one and not the other.

Secondly, in the second version, the variable name breed does not resolve. Why is that?

Comment: Strong argument against version 2 is that it doesn't compile.

Comment: lol. Right, but I can make it if I say `Dog::breed =`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: in the second version, the variable name breed does not resolve. Why is that?

A: Because it's wrong.

You *declare* your class *once*, e.g. in the header.

You may *define* your method implementations either in-line (in the header itself, when you declare the class), or in a separate .cpp (as you did in example 1).
Thess links might help explain further:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/
- http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html